# Why static final variables are accepted in inner classees?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes, final

I know that it's possible to do the following:

```
public class Indeed{
    private class inner {
        static final int try1 = 10;
    }
}
```

Why? what's the point of allowing such a declaration? 
Moreover it's still possible do the same thing in a local class:

```
public void doThing() {
    class LocalClass {
         static final int try1 = 10;
    }
}
```

What's the use of a static final in those bits of code?
I am pretty sure I'll never use them, however I need to understand why they are used as I have an OCPJP7 exam to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just understand `static` and `final`, when class is inited, static variable will be inited and then it never be changed. You can access them inside their scope.

Comment: Well, this is a `static` variable like any other, no mystery here

Comment: IMO, why to differentiate if static final variables are in inner class or main class. They are intended to be used in same way in inner class as you would in any normal class.

Comment: @fge good catch, changed it. Improvised code for the question sorry about that.

Comment: @Jitendra so why in the inner class without static would not work?

Comment: static or non static only change that you need a reference to access it... internal class still need to have an instance to access instance fields

Comment: As to the point of their _usefulness_, uh, you'll have to ask the dev who does that... It is allowed just like variables in interfaces, escapes of `this` in object constructions, etc... No matter the language, if you want to do sh*, you'll do sh*, and one's sh* can be another's sugar :p

Comment: @fmodos ok, then why it works only with "final specified"? and in a local class what's the purpose of a static field ?

Comment: @fge so you agree that there is no much sense in using them?

Comment: @Rollerball "why it works only with final specified" <-- isn't that your real question ultimately? Because that's a good one.

Comment: final is optional... internal class still need an instance, if you set `InternalClass.StaticField=x` is different of `new InternalClass().InstanceField=x`

Comment: @fmodos I have just tried... You cannot declare a `static`, non `final` field in an inner class; they _do_ have to be final. The question is why? I don't know.

Comment: @fge still I don't know why one should use a static field in an inner class. (not a nested class). An inner class is made only to produce an object within the outer object instantiation. Where is the relation with the class?

Comment: @fge I think that's gonna be kind of fixed in Java 8. ctrl +f "se 8" here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: I have no idea either... Maybe to track an invocation count (in which case it would be an `AtomicInteger`? Cannot answer, cannot imagine a valid use, but someone else might

Comment: @Rollerball you cant have static non final in an inner instance class because there is no way to access this class without an instance... if you change the inner class to static it will work

Comment: @fmodos i know that static does not work and it's logic. It should be like that (in inner classes). Still i don't know (my original question's purpose) why static final are allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a static variable is to be shared by all instances of the class. In both examples, you can have several instances of your private class / local class, so as specified they will share static variables among instances. What would be pointless is if you could only instantiate your class once.

**[JLS 8.1.3. : Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)**

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

The way I see it in the specs, is not having to answer the following dilemma:

- static variables of an inner class are shared amongst all instances of the same *outer class instance* (but they can have different values from an outer class instance to another)
- static variables of an inner class are shared amongst all existing instances in the VM, whatever their outer class instances.

Fortunately, when you declare it final, you know it will be the same for every instance, so you don't have to worry about this problem. That's why it is allowed.

Comment: why with final is allowed though?

Answer (score 1):

For the question "why do static fields of inner classes have to be final":

This restriction is stated [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) as

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

But this doesn't tell us why. Let's think about how we use inner classes. Imagine I write (try to) this.

```
public class A{
  private class B{
    static x;
  }
  public void updateX(int y){
    B.x=y;
  }
  public void printX(){
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

What happens when I do this

```
A one = new A();
A two = new A();
one.doStuff(1);
two.doStuff(2);
one.printX();
two.printX();
```

What should be printed? 1 then 2 or 2 twice? x is static so it should only exist in one place (in the `Klass` object of B) but as B is an inner class it should be specific to that instance of A. If we allowed static non final fields we would need to create an instance-specific `Klass` object per instance of the outer class. Which we don't want to have to do!

Static final fields are therefore allowed as they can live in the `Klass` object of B happily, and be shared across all instances of the outer class, because they can never change (being final).